# Docker PostgreSQL service: could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running a PostgreSQL service with Docker. For some reason, PostgreSQL wants to bind to IPV6 - although I haven't specified that anywhere (at least as far as I'm aware).

As a result of this, I am unable to connect to PG. Relevant details follow below:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.6

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get -y install apt-utils \
 && apt-get -y install python3 \
 && apt-get -y install postgresql-plpython3-9.6

COPY sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ 

EXPOSE 5432

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

#### PostgreSQL log file contents

```
LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-10-09 21:22:22 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

I run the container using the following command: `docker run --name my_db_service_cntnr image_tag`

When I run the following command: `docker container port my_db_service_cntnr`, I get nothing returned:

```
me@yourbox:~/path/to/pgdb$ docker container port my_db_service_cntnr 
me@yourbox:~/path/to/pgdb$
```

I know PostgreSQL is running in the container:

```
me@yourbox:~/path/to/pgdb$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
824ffe17c5b9        df:pg               "docker-entrypoint..."   16 hours ago        Up 5 minutes        5432/tcp            my_db_service_cntnr


me@yourbox:/path/to/pgdb$ docker container inspect my_db_service_cntnr | grep Address
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
```

Yet when I attempt to connect to PostgreSQL (using default port of 5432), it fails to connect to the database:

#### Attempting to connect via psql

```
me@yourbox:~/path/to/pgdb$ psql -h 172.17.0.2 -U postgres -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "172.17.0.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
me@yourbox:~/path/to/pgdb$
```

**It seems port 5432 is not being listened to on my machine**, despite me specifying that the PG image `EXPOSE` port 5432:

```
me@yourbox:~/path/to/pgdb$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
lighttpd  1477  www-data    4u  IPv4  22342      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   1645    nobody    5u  IPv4  26954      0t0  TCP CEBERUS:53 (LISTEN)
master    2182      root   12u  IPv4  28720      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
master    2182      root   13u  IPv6  28721      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:25 (LISTEN)
rhythmbox 3149        me   17u  IPv4  33925      0t0  TCP *:3689 (LISTEN)
rhythmbox 3149        me   18u  IPv6  33926      0t0  TCP *:3689 (LISTEN)
cupsd     8432      root   10u  IPv6  87004      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     8432      root   11u  IPv4  87005      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
```

What is causing this error, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: from logs it looks that postgres started - did you try to connect to it?..

Comment: did you modify `listen_address` to `172.17.0.2` in postgres.conf?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm not sure why I would have to do that. I have not come across any documentation that suggests that. Do you have any references to back your suggestion? I ask, because I have successfully run PostgreSQL as a service in Docker without encountering this issue (or having to modify listen_address as you suggest).

Comment: The port won't be published to the hosts address unless you use `-p` when running the container. As for the connection issue, are you on Docker for Mac/Windows?  Can you connect to `psql -h localhost` when using `docker run -p 5432`?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli In order to listen on network iface apart of socket, you have to change listen_address to & or IP... i

Comment: @Matt I'm running on Ubuntu Linux. I will try specifying the port (`-p flag`) when running the container.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Don't worry about the delay, I appreciate you taking the time to answer! On our systems, the problem just "disappeared" between evening and morning (annoying!). Even worse, on the working system, the "could not bind IPv6 socket" still appears before the usual rest of the logging, so it's probably not the (main) cause anyway. Still a mystery :-)

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a complete answer, but should get you closer to an answer. It covers the dockerism's that are required for your debug steps in the question.

Run a postgres container

```
$ CID=$(docker run -d postgres)
$ echo $CID
48024dc71aa446...
```

Get the PID of the container

```
$ PID=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Pid}} $CID)
$ echo $PID
7994
```

Get the logs from the container, check for errors.

```
$ docker logs $CID
```

Process list from the container

```
$ docker exec -ti $CID ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
postgres     1     0  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres
postgres    49     1  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process  
postgres    50     1  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process  
postgres    51     1  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process  
postgres    52     1  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher pr
postgres    53     1  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector proces
postgres    54     1  0 23:19 ?        00:00:00 postgres: bgworker: logical repl
root        66     0  0 23:26 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Run `ss` in the container looking for listening tcp processes (like `lsof`)

```
$ docker exec -ti $CID ss -lntp
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN     0      128          *:5432                     *:*                  
LISTEN     0      128         :::5432                    :::*
```

Outside the container won't report on ports in container namespaces

```
$ ss -lntp
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                                        Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN     0      128                                        *:22                                                     *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=592,fd=3))
LISTEN     0      128                                       :::22                                                    :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=592,fd=4))
```

From the host, you can use `nsenter` to enter the containers namespace and run commands.

```
$ nsenter -t $PID -n ss -lntp
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                                        Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN     0      128                                        *:5432                                                   *:*                   users:(("postgres",pid=7994,fd=3))
LISTEN     0      128                                       :::5432                                                  :::*                   users:(("postgres",pid=7994,fd=4))

$ nsenter -t $PID -n ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
52: eth0@if53: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.3/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Get the IP of the container from Docker

```
$ IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress}}' $CID)
$ echo $IP
172.17.0.3
```

Test the connection

```
$ psql -h $IP -U postgres -p 5432
```

#### Mapped ports

With a mapped port, the ports on the host changes slightly

```
$ CID=$(docker run -d -p 5432:5432 postgres)
$ echo $CID
020f72394fcd...
```

Now the container has a port configured

```
$ docker container port $CID
5432/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5432

$ docker inspect -f {{.NetworkSettings.Ports}} $CID
map[5432/tcp:[{0.0.0.0 5432}]]
```

The port will also be listening on the host

```
$ ss -lntp
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                                        Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN     0      128                                        *:22                                                     *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=592,fd=3))
LISTEN     0      128                                       :::22                                                    :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=592,fd=4))
LISTEN     0      128                                       :::5432                                                  :::*                   users:(("docker-proxy",pid=8571,fd=4))
```

And you can connect to localhost or your hosts IP now

```
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 5432
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have upvoted your answer, since you have provided me with enough information with which to hopefully work out a solution. I have been battling with this issue on and off since I posted this question - there is a lot of conflicting information online (different versions of docker appear to require different commands etc. - all very confusing).

Comment: I reread your answer. It does seem to be quite a lot of work to get Docker up and running?. Lots of utils like `ss`, `nsenter`, `xxd` which I had not even heard of before now - and I'm not sure I understand their outputs, or how to make use of their output. Surely, there must be an easier way to get PostgreSQL "Dockerised"? Last but not the least, could you explain what you're doing with `pgstartup.bin`? where is that hex string coming from?

Comment: I've never experienced the issue you have with postgres. This isn't normal operation, just general docker debug info for when things go awry.

Comment: Sorry about the `nc` thing, it's just what I had handy to test a connection from a monitoring script. It's the [StartupMessage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-message-formats.html) a pg client sends when opening a connection. a `psql` test will suffice

Comment: `docker exec -ti $CID ss -lntp` is the important one. It will tell you what ports are listening inside the container

Comment: I run the last command you suggested, and got this response: State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN     0      128               127.0.0.1:5432   I don't know what that means - or how to use that info. Suggestions on how to connect to PG?

Comment: `ss` just does your `lsof` command, it reports processes listening on ports. Postgres is running and listening on 127.0.0.1/localhost only, so won't be available via the docker 172.17.0.x address.  Normally only the initial run of postgres, while the DB is being set up listens on localhost. It will then stop, and startup listening on all interfaces (`*` like my `ss` output). Running the container with `-p 5432:5432` will allow you to connect via the docker hosts interface to localhost in the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156560/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-matt).